# not enough input arguments fminsearch

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a script in MATLAB that graphs a function in three dimensions using the mesh function and then finds the maximum of the surface. This is my code so far:

```
%% Aquifer, 3D maximum search
figure(2)
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-10:.5:10,-10:.5:10);
h = @(x,y)-(1./(1+(x-.25).^2+(y-.5).^2+x+x.*y));
mesh(h(X,Y)) %graph aquifer surface

aquamax = fminsearch(h,[-5;-5])
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
Error using @(x,y)-(1./(1+(x-.25).^2+(y-.5).^2+x+x.*y))
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fminsearch (line 190)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
```

I've read up on the fminsearch function but I'm not that familiar with it (still a bit of a noob at Matlab). Do I need to rework the code or is it just how I've input things into fminsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `h` function requires 2 scalar inputs, but `fminsearch` only does one input, possibly a vector. Change `h` to `h = @(x)-(1./(1+(x(1)-.25).^2+(x(2)-.5).^2+x(1)+x(1).*x(2)));` and see if that works.